# Positions of a Character in a String with Swift 2

Tags: swift

I'm making a string extension for finding multiple positions a character can occur in a string. This is my code:

```
let letter: Character = "l"

extension String {
    func checkLetter(letter: Character) {
        if let index = self.rangeOfString(AString: String(letter), range: Range<Int>(start: 2, end: 5)  ) {
            print(index)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just completely lost on how to fill in that range part. There keep getting errors. I want to write a while loop which checks for the index of a character in a string. When found it will update a variabele which I can insert in range so it skips the part next time in the whole loop that contained the position of the character found before. Hope this makes it a bit clear. Here's some pseaduo code:

```
extension func
    let range = 0
    while loop: checks if character is in string
        update range to index
        append index to NSarray list
return nsarray list and if none found return nil
```

Comment: Why an extension, there must be a good reason?

Comment: Just so my code looks a bit cleaner and more understandable. Here's the thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285412/how-to-find-all-positions-of-one-string-in-another-string-in-swift2.

Comment: This might help as a starting point: [Find all indices of a search term in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890920/find-all-indices-of-a-search-term-in-a-string).

Comment: Will the next developer wonder what `checkLetter` is and know that it is an extension? Does the name `checkLetter` indicate what the method does, check for what? At a minimum give it a descriptive name or the next developer (could be you next year) will have to find, read and figureout what it does.

Comment: No, but thanks for your feedback. I will call it: findIndexesOfChar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your extension written following the Functional Programming approach.

```
extension String {
    func indexesOfChar(c: Character) -> [Int] {
        return characters
            .enumerate()
            .filter { $0.element == c }
            .map { $0.index }
    }
}
```

Test

```
"Luminetic Land".indexesOfChar("i") // [3, 7]
```

Comment: That's a very nice piece of code m8. Thanks for answering my question!

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference `yourString.characters.indexOf("a")` will give you the index of the first appearance of `"a"` in `yourString`. You could use this in a `while` loop to find `"a"` in the range from the previous index of `"a"` plus one and then add the indexes to an array until the output is negative one.